# Typing over span adds phantom background-color style

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7ph5vfj/

My question is: Can anyone suggest a workaround to this chrome specific bug? My problem is not that the letter X is highlighted, it is that it loses the .foo class and so I can't find it anymore. I would be fine with either the .foo class staying put OR if the background color goes away. I don't even know how to debug this as DOM breakpoints don't fire when this happens.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    DO NOT REPLACE. <span class="foo">END a b c</span> d START la la
</div>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
.foo {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The steps to trigger the bug on chrome are:

- Take your mouse, place the cursor next to the word START
- Click and hold to select text, go to the LEFT and finish the selection at the word END.
- The selection should cover the following text exactly: "END a b c d START". Again, the selection has to be from right to left.
- Type a new character on your keyboard, like 'X'
- If X is highlighted in red, you have triggered the bug.

The bug in particular is that the HTML now looks like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    DO NOT REPLACE. <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">X</span>&nbsp;la la
</div>
```

Where did the .foo class go and where did this background-color style come from? Adding DOM breakpoints to either the div or the span do not fire when this happens.

Comment: Very well done question. I'm curious to learn what's going on there.

Comment: Interesting, it gets the background colour from the class and places it in a style. What's even more interesting is that if the class has a `color` property the span is stripped of its class and wrapped in a `<font>` tag with the color attribute!!!  [Here is an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/yhgp3xcv/)

Comment: Yeah, and if you have `.foo {display:block}` it adds an extra `<br>` in the span. If you have `.foo {display:inline-block}` the span disappears completely. Lovely stuff. No solution though; I tested with `id` and `role`, but those attributes disappear too.

Comment: After some research I found this document that seems to be the one that should specify these behaviours: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html tho I didn't had the time to read it so I cannot tell if there's any clue in it. As of workaround why not just override the behaviour with javascript?

Comment: @MrLister: I was unable to get the <span> to disappear when adding inline-block. If I could, that would possibly be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll: Javascript would be fine, the problem is how do I find the element in the DOM (with my real HTML that has a lot of stuff going on). I don't want to hard-code on the color as different spans have different colors and they can change by user-input. One idea that I had was to have a keydown listener and modify the span on keydown when there is a selection, but that seems fraught with complications (If they press ctrl-c, I want to preserve the formatting for example)

Comment: @AnilRedshift Oh, so sorry to get your hopes up. I meant if the `display:inline-block` was the only property in the `.foo` block, not in addition to the color. Can't think of a solution.

Comment: I meant to detect any kind of change made to the content, if the changes would trigger the bug prevent the delegation and then make the modifications dynamically (practicaly rewriting the edit API on-demand).
Tho I have to admit that it might be a way big overhad for such a seemingly negligible problem, and it's just easier to rethink the way you application works or wait this bug gets resolved (if it will ever be).

Comment: looking to hack around this as well!  here's the chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498086&q=contenteditable&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

hoping that this receives the proper attention and gets resolved soon!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really clean code, but if you wrap your span.foo with another span, the problem seems to be fixed.

`<div contenteditable="true">
DO NOT REPLACE. <span><span class="foo">END a b c</span></span> d START la la
</div>`